# Can I preserve fillable fields in a PDF with Apple Cups?

Tags: pdf, printers, cups

I have setup a remote Ubuntu server, it has cups-pdf on it. I have a Windows 10 client it is able to print to it using an HP Universal Printer driver.

The thing is, we're trying to send fillable pdfs and the fillable fields are stripped out... that is probably obvious but I want to know if it's possible to keep the fields...

Are they already gone by the time they hit the server or can I stop them from being stripped out on the cups side?

I know it would be easier to just do file upload... it's an interop problem where printing is the best way to get the files around.

Comment: This is from Chrome, they're rendering a PDF with some PDF library but the PDF was emailed to me and the fillable fields are still there. When I print them to the cups-pdf printer they're stripped out. Seems like it's obvious but wondering if we can prevent that.

Comment: "print visible render as an image" yeah I think that happens anyway (flattens PDF with filled in values in fillable fields). I will try and dump the process that cups-pdf goes through. I just have no idea what to look for/markers of editable fields.